# How to convert a java map's values?

Tags: java, collections

I have a `TreeMap<String, WrappedObject>` and I wanna convert it to a new, independent `TreeMap<String, UnwrappedObject>`. What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those cases where `Map.forEach` comes in handy:

```
    Map<String, WrappedObject> in = ... ;
    Map<String, UnwrappedObject> out = new TreeMap<>();
    in.forEach((k, v) -> out.put(k, v.unwrap()));
```

(Assuming that `WrappedObject.unwrap()` does the obvious thing.)

The big advantage in brevity here is that `Map.forEach` passes the key and value separately, whereas the loop or streams approach requires use of `Map.Entry` instances and calls to its getters for the keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `unwrap()` unwraps a `WrappedObject`, you can't get much simpler than this.

```
TreeMap<String, UnwrappedObject> out = new TreeMap<>();
for(Entry<String, WrappedObject> entry : in.entrySet())
    out.put(entry.getKey(), unwrap(entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Java 8:

```
Map<String, UnwrappedObject> newMap = wrappedObjectMap.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                              e -> e.getValue().getWrappedObject());
                                  // assuming this method exists to get the UnwrappedObject
```

This [collects all entries of the old map using a collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) that takes the same key in the entry (`Map.Entry::getKey` is equivalent to `e -> e.getKey()`), and sets the value to be the result of unwrapping the object.

To have the returned map of type `TreeMap`, use the [`Collectors.toMap` that takes a supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-):

```
TreeMap<String, Object> newMap = wrappedObjectMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                    e -> e.getValue().getWrappedObject(),
                                   (v1, v2) -> v1,
                                   TreeMap::new));
 // third parameter can be any merge function in this case since conflicts should not occur
```

Comment: This doesn't give me a `TreeMap`.

Comment: @SoniEx2 Edited. You can use an overloaded method of `Collectors`.

Comment: Is this the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Compared to a simple loop, I guess the loop is simpler. But it still looks a simple stream pipeline to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Two questions: can you use Guava, and does the returned map need to be written to, or just read from?

If you can use Guava, and only need read access to the transformed map, you could use `Maps.transformValues(NavigableMap, Function)`.

The advantage here is that there's virtually no cost other than the transformation of the values, yet the navigability of the map is retained. Other methods that construct a new `TreeMap` suffer from the cost of re-inserting every key.